# When to override updateTrackingAreas

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview, nstrackingarea

So I have a quite big `NSScrollView` with several custom views in it. In these custom views i'm overriding `-(void)updateTrackingAreas` like this:

```
- (void)updateTrackingAreas
{    
    [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];

    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                                options:(NSTrackingCursorUpdate |
                                                         NSTrackingActiveWhenFirstResponder |
                                                         NSTrackingInVisibleRect)
                                                  owner:self 
                                               userInfo:nil];

    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}
```

But somehow I feel this is a little unefficient since I have about 50 instances of my custom view in the NSScrollView and only about 5 of them are visible at a time and this way I'm updating the tracking areas of non-visible views.

So I thought I would skip updating the tracking areas if the view is not in NSScrollView's visible rect. Something like:

```
- (void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    if(!NSIntersectsRect([self frame], [[self superview] visibleRect]))
    {
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This seems to be working out well but I'm not sure if this is safe.

Does anyone have some advice on this matter?